# Vert.x use OpenSslEngine for HTTP server

Tags: java, openssl, netty, vert.x

I'm trying to use OpenSSL engine on an HTTP server.

My configuration looks like

```
        HttpServerOptions options = new HttpServerOptions()
            .setSsl(config.getSsl())
            .setSslEngineOptions(new OpenSSLEngineOptions())
            .setClientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUEST)
            .setKeyStoreOptions(keystoreOptions)
            .setTrustStoreOptions(truststoreOptions)
            .setEnabledSecureTransportProtocols(enabledSecureTransportProtocols);
```

I'm using Vert.x 3.6.2, which brings Netty dependencies 4.1.30. I also added to my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-tcnative</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.20.Final</version>
        <classifier>linux-x86_64-fedora</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Because my HTTP server is deployed on RHEL 7 with OpenSSL 1.0.1 (I know it's old). I'm getting the following error:

`io.vertx.core.VertxException: OpenSSL is not available`

And as I can see from logs, netty handler try to load this native library netty-tcnative and can't find it in the classpath:

`netty-tcnative not in the classpath; OpenSslEngine will be unavailable`. I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you installed the Apache Portable Runtime (APR) ? Netty needs both APR and OpenSSL

Comment: Thx for your comment, yep libapr-1.so was missing. Unfortunately, I cannot install it on my machine. I made it work by using boringssl.